# Where does the limitation of 10^15 in D.J. Bernstein's 'primegen' program come from?

Tags: cryptography, reverse-engineering

At http://cr.yp.to/primegen.html you can find sources of program that uses Atkin's sieve to generate primes. As the author says that it may take few months to answer an e-mail sent to him (I understand that, he sure is an occupied man!) I'm posting this question.

The page states that 'primegen can generate primes up to 1000000000000000'. I am trying to understand why it is so. There is of course a limitation up to 2^64 ~ 2 * 10^19 (size of long unsigned int) because this is how the numbers are represented. I know for sure that if there would be a huge prime gap  (> 2^31) then printing of numbers would fail. However in this range I think there is no such prime gap.

Either the author overestimated the bound (and really it is around 10^19) or there is a place in the source code where the arithmetic operation can overflow or something like that.

The funny thing is that you actually MAY run it for numbers > 10^15:

```
./primes 10000000000000000 10000000000000100
10000000000000061
10000000000000069
10000000000000079
10000000000000099
```

and if you believe Wolfram Alpha, it is correct.

Some facts I had "reverse-engineered":

1. numbers are sifted in batches of 1,920 * PRIMEGEN_WORDS = 3,932,160 numbers (see primegen_fill function in primegen_next.c)
2. PRIMEGEN_WORDS controls how big a single sifting is - you can adjust it in primegen_impl.h to fit your CPU cache,
3. the implementation of the sieve itself is in primegen.c file - I assume it is correct; what you get is a bitmask of primes in pg->buf (see primegen_fill function)
4. The bitmask is analyzed and primes are stored in pg->p array.

I see no point where the overflow may happen.

Comment: I don't recall, but assuming DJB used unsigned integers for the sieving primes (thus 32-bit numbers), and assuming unsigned integers for the primes generated by the sieve (thus 64-bit numbers) the limit on the algorithm is actually 2^64. The comment by DJB may have been a _practical_ limit, since sieving at that range takes an extreme amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I was on my computer to look, but I suspect you would have different success if you started at 1 as your lower bound.

Comment: What do you mean by that? "./primes 1 10000000000000099" starts without segfault or anything. It will take forever to sieve this range, though, so I cannot confirm it does work for this range by these means. Nevertheless, if this _would_ crash, then the trick is to explain **why**, not to state the obvious fact that you see "Segmentation fault" in your console...

Answer (score 0):

Just from the algorithm, I would conclude that the upper bound comes from the 32 bit numbers. 
The page mentiones Pentium-III as CPU so my guess it is very old and does not use 64 bit.

2^32 are approx 10^9. Sieve of Atkins (which the algorithm uses) requires N^(1/2) bits (it uses a big bitfield). Which means in 2^32 big memory you can make (conservativ) N approx 10^15. As this number is a rough conservative upper bound (you have system and other programs occupying memory, reserving address ranges for IO,...) the real upper bound is/might be higher.

Comment: That would be a super-over-estimation: sqrt(10^15) is approx 31622776. If this is a bitfield then it can easily fit in 4MBs. This is of course way below the limit of 2GB. To support this argument - if you run primegen you'll see that actually the memory consumption is very low.